# How do I make external methods available in another class?

Tags: php, oop

Im new to OOP but Im getting there quite fast.

I have a class with a single method for connecting to an api. I have another class with various methods containing the various endpoint and queries I use with this api.

I want to be able to only have to call the first class once and use the methods from that class within the variables class rather than call the class inside each method over and over.

For example:

At the moment Im doing this.

```
class classname
{
    public function name1
    {
        # some code
        $request = new someClassName();
        $var = $request->functionName();
    }

    public function name2
    {
        # some code

        $request = new someClassName();
        $var = $request->functionName();
    }
}
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
class classname
{
    public $request = new someClassName();

    public function name1
    {
        # some code
        $var = $request->functionName();
    }

    public function name2
    {
        # some code
        $var = $request->functionName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [$this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and create a constructor.

```
class classname {

    public $request = null;

    public function __construct(){
       $this->request = new someClassName();
    }

    public function name1{

        //some code
        $var = $this->request->functionName();

    }

    public function name2{

        //some code
        $var = $this->request->functionName();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking it 1 step further, you can inject the dependency `someClassName` into your class, and then expose it via public methods. Also, made the property private so that is it not accessible from the outside.

For clarity, I've renamed `someClassName` to `Request` and `classname` to `Handler`.

```
class Handler
{
    private $_request = null;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public fuction handle()
    {
        return $this->_request->process();
    }
}

// Inject the dependency into the class from the outside. 
$handler = new Handler(new Request());

// Call the public method on the class to perform actions. 
echo $handler->handle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can implement :

If your **someClassName** has only one method to connect to the api , i mean you don't have other dependencies to this class (injection etc ) , your can declare this method as static and then call it in your **classname** .

```
class someClassName
{

    public static function functionName()
    {
        # some code

    }
}

class classname
{

    public function name1
    {
        # some code
        $var = someClassName::functionName();
    }

    public function name2
    {
        # some code
        $var = someClassName::functionName();
    }
}
```

Or you can also write in inside a trait like the example bellow :

```
trait sometraitName
    {
        protected   function functionName()
        {
            # some code
        }
    }

class classname
{
    use sometraitName;

    public function name1
    {
        # some code
        $var = $this->functionName();
    }

    public function name2
    {
        # some code
        $var = $this->functionName();
    }
}
```